# How can I have per project Debug Configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have configured some VM arguments inside the Debug Configuration. However, these settings are saved in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches\Program.launch`, which is outside the version control. Indeed, the whole `.metadata` folder is.

But this is something I wish to be shared amongst all the devs working on the project. In other words, I want per project Debug/Run Configuration.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launcher (`.launch` file) can be stored outside of `.metadata`: go to "Run → Run Configurations...", choose your launcher, and in its "Common" tab choose "Save as: Shared file". This will save the `.launch` file in the chosen folder, and then it can be committed to your version control system.